# How to start and call methods of a normal java project on a tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a "normal java application project" with some methods within the classes and the main method - the methods' return values like strings or arrays.

The servlet project and the normal java app project are in the same workspace. 
The servlet run on tomcat.

How can I start the "normal java app project" from the servlet?
How can I call the "normal java app project-methods" from the servlet?

I want to create a button which calls the methods and shows me the return value of them.

Comment: Move the code from your main method to servlets doGet/doPost method (or create new class which executes the code you want to call). Maybe you can provide the code from your main method to make it clearer.

Comment: The "normal app" is a huge thing with running corba server as well , i think i cant move the code easly to the doGet/doPost methode ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pack that normal "app" as a Jar-File an include it into your Web-Project. Then deploy the whole application (with included jar) to your tomcat.

If you like an easy way whitin your development area yout can Use Maven or Ant for compiling the normal application and copy it into your other project.

Comment: As i said to Carl the "normal app" is a huge thing with running corba server as well thank you for pointing the direction, i will look into maven/ant .